# downgrade to IE8 32bit on running Windows 64bit

Tags: windows-7

1. I need to run `agfa-impax client` in `IE8 32bit` on `Windows 7 64bit`
2. can i make `32 bit iexplorer.exe` to be default

i don't have option to go for windows 32bit

appreciate if any help

Comment: Publish with RemoteApp or XenAPP IE8 32bits ? Even if you upgrade to Windows 8, 8.1 that will continue to work.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options you can try is to remove existing IE (which is probably higher version). Make sure you download the IE8 version prior to removal of existing IE.
Reboot once compltetion. 
Now install IE8.
You wont' be able to downgrade your windows to 32bit unfortunately unless you want to completely reinstall.

Comment: i am not considering to convert from windows 764bit to windows 7 32bit

Comment: i just need to downgrade to IE8 32bit while windows 7 stay 64bit

Answer (score 0):

On a 64-bit system with IE8 installed, it actually *requires* you to use the 32-bit version as the default.  The 64-bit version of IE can't be the default, even on a 64-bit machine.  Also, since Windows 7 originally shipped with IE8 by default, you will never find a download option for it.  Any versions you find will be for Vista or XP.  Those won't work on your machine.

If you have a later version of IE installed you must remove it first (you can't run two different versions on the same machine).  There are some posts on the internet that suggest you remove it from the Windows Features list.  This is not correct, as it will remove IE but won't downgrade you.

To actually perform a downgrade, do the following:

1. Go to the Programs and Features control panel like you were going to uninstall an application.  On that window, there will be a link on the left that says "View installed updates".  Click that.

[image: Programs and Features control panel]

2. Find whatver version of IE you have installed in the list and hit Uninstall.

[image: Installed Updates]

3. This will restore whatever version of IE was on the machine before the current one so you may have to do this several times until you land on the correct version.  For example, if you upgraded to IE9, then 10, then 11, you will have to remove IE11, then 10, then 9 again.

On a 64-bit system you will have two Internet Explorer icons on your Start Menu; one that says Internet Explorer (64-bit), and one that just says Internet Explorer.  That's the 32-bit version you want.